# How to read copy the content of a folder

Tags: powershell

Hi all I have written the following script which lists the number of folders or files in desc order , based on user input that folder or file gets copied on to the new location. This script works perfect but I do not want to copy folder but only its content for example if there is a folder called transaction, so i would like to copy whatever is inside transaction but not transaction folder itself.

```
$content = get-childitem 'C:\Users\srk\Desktop\Srk_test'


#Put the sorted data into a variable

$sortedContent = $content |  Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending 

#Create a counter to allow you to index items

$count = 0

foreach ($item in $sortedContent)
{

#Edit: Now with auto-incrementing counter

Write-Host ("{0}: {1}" -f $count++, $item.Name)

$count++ 
}

$itemNumber = Read-Host "Enter a number for the item to copy"
#Copy the item at the number provided above by the user

$confirmation = Read-Host "Are you Sure You Want To Proceed:"

if ($confirmation -eq 'y') {

$sortedContent[$itemNumber] | Copy-Item  -Destination 'C:\test\'

write-output "Your folder has copied to C:\test"
}
elseif
{
write-host "Please try again"
}
```

Comment: The output folders which i am getting are listed in date time folder for example 03-07-2014 when the descending line gets executed how can i convert this format and display it like mon 07 April 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, first it checks whether item is a folder then copies its contents recursively:

```powershell
...
if ($confirmation -eq 'y') {
  if($sortedContent[$itemNumber].PSIsContainer -eq $true){ 
     $src = $sortedContent[$itemNumber].FullName + "\*"    
     Copy-Item -Path -Recurse -Destination 'C:\test\'
     Write-Output "Your folder has copied to C:\test"
  }
  else{
     $sortedContent[$itemNumber] | Copy-Item  -Destination 'C:\test\'
     Write-Output "Your file has copied to C:\test"
  }
}
elseif
...
```

Comment: The output folders which i am getting are listed in date time folder for example 03-07-2014 when the descending line gets executed how can i convert this format and display it like mon 07 April 2014

Comment: The sorted content is actually folders which have dates on them, so i would like to have a nice datetime format on the folders once they displayed

Comment: Please ask a separate question.

Comment: HI Raf thanks for replying i have posted it here in seperate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656803/how-to-format-datetime-in-powershell

Answer (score 0):

You can send the get-childitem results to the pipeline:

```
get-childitem $sortedContent[$itemNumber]|Copy-Item -Destination 'C:\test'
```

Comment: using the above line of code i am getting an error, get-childitem cannot find path "This is the path where i am trying to copy the files from " but if i take the get-childitem off i am able to copy the folder but than i am back to the same problem

Comment: You may need to include the full path, like so: get-childitem "C:\Users\srk\Desktop\Srk_test\$($sortedContent[$itemNumber])" | Copy-Item -Destination 'C:\test'