# How to format datetime in powershell

Tags: datetime, powershell

I am trying to format the datetime for my folders once they are sorted into descending order . At the moment I have datetime format like 25-04-2014 and I would like to to get displayed 2th april 2014 I am using this code but dont know how to use the formatting

```
$sortedContent = $content |  Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending
```

Comment: Literally first hit on google: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx

Comment: Raf i read bout it, but all my folders get the dates on which they have created but i am not sure how to pipe formatting with the above command so they dont appear as 25-04-2014 but they appear as 25 April 2014

Comment: i want exactly this output based on my command which i am using to sort out the stuff in desc order Thursday, August 30, 2007 11:13:51 AM

Comment: still cannot figure it out

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe the result to [Format-Table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849892.aspx) and explicitly tell what format you want to use.

Here is an example with ls:

```
$format = @{Expression={$_.Mode};Label="Mode";width=10},`
    @{Expression={$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("D")};Label="LastWriteTime";width=25},`
    @{Expression={$_.Name};Label="Name";width=100}

ls | sort LastWriteTime -descending | format-table $format
```

Of course, you can use the [proper date format](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx) in the "ToString" call.